# Laravel: RESTful controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

If you had defined a RESTful controller in *routes.php*

```
Route::controller('users', 'UserController');
```

and the following functions in the `UserController` class

```
public function getLogin() { ... }
public function postLogin() { ... }
```

Do we even need to define `Route::post('user/login', 'UserController@postLogin')` anymore?

Answer (score 1):

> Do we even need to define Route::post('user/login',
>   'UserController@postLogin') anymore?

No - because the RESTful controller route includes that.

You can test this by running `php artisan routes` to see a list of all *registered* routes in your application.

Comment: Thanks. In my `php artisan routes` output, I have `GET|HEAD user/login/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}` which will be handled by `UserController@getLogin`. Do I need to take care of the `{one?}/{two?}...`? Same thing with the `PUT` entry.

Comment: @moey you don't have to worry about those parameter, the `?` denotes optional parameter. If you do pass parameter to your controller method, say `@getLogin`, you can automatically catch the parameter by declaring `public function getLogin($anyName) {}`

Comment: @JofryHS: +1, thanks. So, does it mean `getLogin($param1, $param2)` will take care of the 2 arguments in _/user/login/arg1/arg2_?